# ssh tunneling (ksh: 23: not found)

Tags: networking, ssh, connection, tunnel

hello all i am try to tunnel with command from my windows using cygwin to `$ ssh -D localhost:9999 xxx@sdf.lonestar.org 23`
it is promit me password and after i do that

> ksh: 23: not found
>   Malek@Malek-VAIO ~

Comment: Please remove the telnet tag, this has nothing to do with telnet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to specify that the remote ssh port is 23. You're close

```
ssh -D localhost:9999 xxx@sdf.lonestar.org -p 23
```

Without the `-p` you're telling ssh to execute the command `23` when it connects to the remote host (which of course isn't a command).